# jQuery switch statement(?)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to write a "switch statement" so if one particular (let's call it 'yourdomain.com') external URL matches it does not open in a new window, the rest will. Can someone lend a hand in teaching me?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a[href^="http://"]')
        .not('[href*="http://mydomain.com"]')
        .attr('target', '_blank');
```

e.g.

mydomain.com = this will not open a new window because it's my URL

yourdomain.com = this particular URL will not open in a new window even though it's an external URL

anyotherdomain.com = every other external URL besides the one above will open in a new window

Comment: What seems to be the problem?  Seems to work fine to me.  http://jsfiddle.net/2PJPR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding another .not()

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a[href^="http://"]')
        .not('[href*="http://mydomain.com"]').not('[href*="http://yourdomain.com"]')
        .attr('target', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
     var elms = $('a[href^="http://"]');
     $.each(elms, function() {
          var current_link = $(this).attr("href");
          if (current_link == "yoururl") {
               $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
          }
     });
});
```

could this be helpful?

Comment: Just by looking at it, would this work for one particular external URL? (e.g. mydomain.com is my URL and I would need yourdomain.com not to open in a new window but any other URL would.

Comment: Thanks, Angelo. I posted the solution above. I appreciate your help.